# Why is the year missing from bibtex rendered via citation.js?

Tags: javascript, bibtex, citations, csl

I'm using node to run [citation.js](https://citation.js.org/) to turn bibtex into HTML. Unfortunately the year is missing in the rendered HTML and I cannot see why.

**test.js:**

```
var Cite = require("citation-js");

var bibtex =
'@article{id, ' +
'  author={Happy Larry},' +
'  date={2017-01-01},' +
'  title="A Lovely Title"' +
'}';

var opts = {
    type: 'html',
    style: 'citation-vancouver',
}

var data = new Cite(bibtex, opts);

var g = data.get();

console.log(g);
```

**Output:**

```
$ node ./test.js
<div class="csl-bib-body">
  <div data-csl-entry-id="id" class="csl-entry">
    <div class="csl-left-margin">1. </div><div class="csl-right-inline">Larry H. A Lovely Title.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would expect the year to be in there somewhere. Yet it fails to materialise no matter which CSL style I use. I've tried several chunks of bibtex, and I've downloaded several CSL styles from citationstyles.org. Everything else works as expected **apart** from the year, which is always missing.

Is this a bug in citation.js?

I notice that the year is missing in the output on the [demo page](https://citation.js.org/demo/).

Comment: (reported and underlying problem identified at https://github.com/larsgw/citation.js/issues/52 and https://github.com/Juris-M/citeproc-js/issues/48)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is made in accordance with [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/5095300).

---

As [@Rintze Zelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712389/rintze-zelle) also said in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45333178/#comment77689858_45333178), this is (was) indeed a bug in Citation.js. It's fixed in [`v0.3.0-12`](https://github.com/larsgw/citation.js/blob/640f4402899c69f49ad4a54ccd40eee190805d7c/CHANGELOG.md#030-12---2017-08-01). [This more general bug report](https://github.com/larsgw/citation.js/issues/53) in Citation.js has more info on the problem.